# For-loop that loops through a list of input integers gets stuck on the first conditional

Tags: python, list, sorting, integer, conditional-statements

A simple program to read a list of integers and determine if it is in ascending or descending order, or out of order, outputs only the first print statement the number of times as the number of list elements, and does continue to the remaining conditionals.

Any help understanding where I have gone wrong will be greatly appreciated.

```
int_num = input("Enter how many integers you have?: ")
int1 = input("Enter 1st integer: ")
int2 = input("Enter 2nd integer: ")
int3 = input("Enter 3rd integer: ")
int4 = input("Enter 4th integer: ")
int5 = input("Enter 5th integer: ")
int6 = input("Enter 6th integer: ")
n_seq = [int1, int2, int3, int4, int5, int6]

for int in n_seq:
    if [0] < [1] < [2] < [3] < [4] < [5]:
        print("Your sequence is sorted in ascending order.")
    elif [0] > [1] > [2] > [3] > [4] > [5]:
        print("Your sequence is sorted in descending order.")
    else:
        print("Your sequence is out of order.")
```

The above program outputs this:

```
Your sequence is sorted in ascending order.
Your sequence is sorted in ascending order.
Your sequence is sorted in ascending order.
Your sequence is sorted in ascending order.
Your sequence is sorted in ascending order.
Your sequence is sorted in ascending order.
```

Comment: Give some more information on what inputs resulted in these outputs. And don't use the word `int` as your iterator variable, `int` is a type and a function in python. Use something other than `int` in your `for int in n_seq:` line.

Comment: Do you understand why?  Because 1 < 2, and 2 < 3, and 3 < 4, etc.  To do what you're doing, forget the `for` loop and do `if n_seq[0] < n_seq[1] < n_seq[2]...`.

Comment: `sorted(n_seq) == n_seq`

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions. @TimRoberts Eliminating the for loop and, with respect to if statements, adding the list name before the element in brackets made it work. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a loop for that. You can simply do:

```
if int1 < int2 < int3 < int4 < int5 < int6:
    print("Your sequence is sorted in ascending order.")
elif int1 > int2 > int3 > int4 > int5 > int6:
    print("Your sequence is sorted in descending order.")
```

Also, all of the `input`s need to be converted to integers before comparison:

```
int1 = int(input("Enter 1st integer: "))
....
int5 = int(input("Enter 5th integer: "))
int6 = int(input("Enter 6th integer: "))
```

When you are using a loop, you are iterating over the elements and checking if `[0]` is greater than `[1]` ..... until `[6]` and vice versa. Of course, that is already in ascending order which then prints it is sorted in ascending order.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating, this helped me understand the issue. I tried to use the int function on the input as given, but for some reason it kept giving me a traceback error saying str element cannot be called. 

I did ultimately resolve the issue by eliminating the for loop as you said, and used the list name with the elements in brackets in the context of the conditional statements, like Tim Roberts indicated in the thread above. 

Like this: if n_seq[0] < n_seq[1] < n_seq[2] < n_seq[3] < n_seq[4] < n_seq[5]:

Comment: @Psiberian_Mushky Was this python2 or python3? Function `input` behaves differently in python2 and python3.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't use `int_num` and appears to only work for exactly six numbers. You can use loops to adapt the behaviour to different possible number of numbers:

```py
n = int(input("How many integers: "))

l = []
for i in range(n):
  l.append(int(input("Enter next integer: ")))

is_sorted = True
for i in range(n-1):
  if not l[i] <= l[i+1]:
    is_sorted = False

if is_sorted:
  print("Your sequence is sorted in increasing order.")
else:
  print("Your sequence is NOT sorted in increasing order.")
```

Or, more pythonic, using builtin function `all`:

```py
n = int(input("How many integers: "))

l = []
for i in range(n):
  l.append(int(input("Enter next integer: ")))

is_sorted = all(l[i] <= l[i+1] for i in range(n-1))

if is_sorted:
  print("Your sequence is sorted in increasing order.")
else:
  print("Your sequence is NOT sorted in increasing order.")
```

Or, even more pythonic, using builtin functions `all` and `zip`:

```py
n = int(input("How many integers: "))

l = []
for i in range(n):
  l.append(int(input("Enter next integer: ")))

is_sorted = all(a <= b for a, b in zip(l, l[1:]))

if is_sorted:
  print("Your sequence is sorted in increasing order.")
else:
  print("Your sequence is NOT sorted in increasing order.")
```

Documentation on builtin functions `all` and `zip`:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html